# Appreciate grammar for contracts writing

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I am currently working on contracts revisions and re-phrasing of some clauses. I often wonder how to use the correct tense or tenses. What is the appropriate wording tense to use for contracts?

Comment: I would say that you need legal advice for writing contracts; but in general they are about promising that you or the other party **will do** certain things.

Comment: This will depend on the contract.  Maybe one for Law.SE, but check there first.

Comment: Are you asking about the tenses throughout all contracts, or just about the words "With best regards"?

Comment: You will need to be more specific. Most clauses either specify that the parties "agree" (present tense) to do something, or "will" do something (future tense)    Of course, it is the skill of a lawyer to write contracts that are easy to enforce and don't have loopholes.  But there is no special rule for tense when writing contracts.  Note that his is about "learning English" and and we can't give specific legal advice.

Comment: While one can get help about the meaning and effect of specific contract language on law.se,(where I am a frequent poster)  they will not give specific legal advice, which includes drafting or revising actual contact language.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to understand about contracts is that a contract is **not** words on paper, a contract is an agreement between two (or more) parties. The words are just to make the details of the agreement clear. Without an agreement, there is no contract (contract law calls this "a meeting of minds").

There is no special tense or aspect required for contracts. A contract may use any tense that expresses the agreement. Simple present and simple future constructions are often used, but many other constructions can be used as long as they express the agreement of the parties to the contract clearly. Conditional forms are also common. Progressive and perfect forms are not unknown.

Contacts often use language such as:

> - The parties agree that if Party A does X then party B will do Y.
> - The parties agree that  Party A will do X and party B will do Y.
> - The parties agree that  Party A will do X, but if X is not done by {date} then party B will receive an additional $10,000 from party A.
> - The parties understand that party A is engaged in constructing building G, and any delay in payments under this agreement that would hinder this project will be a materiel breach of this agreement.
> - This agreement will enter into effect on 1 Jan 2025 or when party B secures construction financing, which ever is later, but if financing is not secured on or before 1 Jan 2028, this agreement is canceled and shall never enter into effect.
> - All notices required under this agreement shall be sent to the relevant party's postal address, as listed in section D, by USPS certified mail, with a copy sent by email to the addresses listed in section D1. If a party changes its address, notice shall be sent to all other parties at least 30 days before the effective date of the change.

Notice the range  of tenses, aspects,. and forms used. Actual contracts may use various other forms as well.

Lawyers often imitate contracts that have stood up in previous court cases, using the same language with only trivial modifications. This can lead to the preservation of quite old-fashioned language, with no good legal reason for its use.